# Error when building QEMU arm for Windows

Tags: windows, arm, qemu

I want to to build QEMU arm for windows. For that I execute the following command:

```
/configure –target-list=arm-softmmu and make.
```

when I  executing make command I get the following error.

```
Makefile:24: no file name for `-include'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `vl.o', needed by `all'. Stop.
make: *** [subdir-libhw32] Error 2
```

How I can resolve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: `Makefile:24: no file name for '-include'` is a rule at line 24 suppressing the error when the given make fragment doesn't exist. My guess it needs to be there either way ... besides, your command definitely won't work this way. Please copy it verbatim!

Comment: Which are the commands I want to use to build QEMU ARM for windows?any idea

Comment: if you are trying to install with binaries follow this link : https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/W32#Debian_based_cross_builds. Look for your windows type (32 or 64 bit) and follow the instructions.                                      
If you don't need the binaries and can work with .exe directly,  you can download from this link : https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/